# Makefile.am: How to list all files (of specific extension) in `foo_HEADERS`?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

In a `Makefile.am`, there is the following rule that mentions all `*.h` files in that specific folder (several hundreds of them):

```
foo_HEADERS = file1.h file2.h ...
```

As the project evolves, new header files are being added to that folder, and I am looking for a method that picks up all .h files automatically.  What doesn't work is to use Makefile stuff like `$(wildcard)`.

Respective `Makefile` is one of the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` in `configure.ac` so I came up with the following:

## In `Makefile.am`:

```
foo_HEADERS = @FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES@

EXTRA_HEADERS =
```

## In `configure.ac`:

Add `AC_SUBST` for `FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES`:

```bash
# Build a list of all .h files in  $(srcdir)/include/foo  as using
# make variables like $(wildcard) won't pan out as desired.
ac_include_foo_h_files=`ls $srcdir/include/foo/*.h`
ac_include_foo_h_files=`basename -a $ac_include_foo_h_files`
AC_SUBST(FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES, "`echo $ac_include_foo_h_files`")
```

## Question:

My solution works as expected, but I am unsure w.r.t. it's generic enought to work in all OSes supported by autotools.

1. Is there a better, more generic approach, in particular for explicit `ls .../*.h` and `basename -a ...` and `echo`<sup>A)</sup>?
2. In case my approach is the way to go, why must `EXTRA_HEADERS` be set<sup>B)</sup> in `Makefile.am`?

---

<sup>A)</sup> The `echo` is needed to get rid of newlines in `ac_include_foo_h_files`.

<sup>B)</sup> Otherwise I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a Makefile.am, there is the following rule that mentions all *.h
> files in that specific folder (several hundreds of them):
>
> ```
> foo_HEADERS = file1.h file2.h ...
> ```
>
> As the project evolves, new header files are being added to that
> folder, and I am looking for a method that picks up all .h files
> automatically.

The canonical and most appropriate way to do this is to list all the files explicitly. There being hundreds of them is unusual and says something (I don't know what) about the project, but does not change the fact.  It ought to be the build system that is authoritative for what gets built and (in this case) installed.  **Automake does not define any other supported way.** And it's not that hard.

> Respective `Makefile.am` is one of the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` in `configure.ac`

Are you sure?  The corresponding `Makefile` should be in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`, but not `Makefile.am` (nor `Makefile.in`).  Supposing that you meant it is the `Makefile` that is listed in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`, this in `Makefile.am` ...

> ```
> foo_HEADERS = @FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES@
>
> EXTRA_HEADERS =
> ```

... is relying on Automake to pass the `@FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES@` through to the `Makefile.in` that it generates, where it will be meaningful to `configure`.  This also assumes that Automake does not rely on any of its own analysis of the variable's value, which I think is true but cannot confirm.

> Add `AC_SUBST` for `FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES`:
>
> ```
> # Build a list of all .h files in  $(srcdir)/include/foo  as using
> # make variables like $(wildcard) won't pan out as desired.
> ac_include_foo_h_files=`ls $srcdir/include/foo/*.h`
> ac_include_foo_h_files=`basename -a $ac_include_foo_h_files`
> AC_SUBST(FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES, "`echo $ac_include_foo_h_files`")
> ```

If you want to hack on `configure.ac` then you *really* ought to get a better grasp on shell programming.  Use modern `$()` instead of `` for command substitution.  Do not interpose `ls` where your glob by itself already provides the file list you want.  And expanding a variable as an argument to `echo`, just to (re-)capture that? You have newlines in the variable's value only because you are unwisely capturing the output of `ls` in the first place, but even having done that, the `echo` trick is a weird way to solve the problem.

Also `$(srcdir)` is a command substitution, which will probably fail.  You seem to want a parameter expansion instead.  And POSIX `basename` does not document any option arguments, just filenames.

And do not create or use your own variables with the `ac_` name prefix.  Autoconf reserves that prefix for its own internal use.

> Is there a better, more generic approach, in particular for explicit ls .../*.h and basename -a ... and echo?

If I were writing that (though I wouldn't; see above), it might look more like this:

```
FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES=
for header in "${srcdir}"/include/foo/*.h; do
  FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES="${FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES} ${header##*/}"
done

# Mark FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES as an output variable
AC_SUBST([FOO_INCLUDE_HFILES])
```

That assumes only features of the POSIX shell, btw; if I were writing for Bash then I'd probably use an array instead of a loop, and I might use `pushd` / `popd` to avoid the need for basename.

> In case my approach is the way to go, why must `EXTRA_HEADERS` be set in `Makefile.am`?

Your approach is *not* the way to go.  It does not conform to Automake's documented requirements, as already discussed.  I can't explain exactly why it makes a difference to define an empty `EXTRA_HEADERS` variable in this case, but I take it as a result of your misuse of Automake.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It's `Makefile`, not `Makefile.am` that's in AC_CONFIG_FILES.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of `foo/*.h` files becomes to large to be obvious for a handwritten list of files after `foo_HEADERS =`, and since Automake insists on a fixed list of files, I would go the following route to keep the list of files added to `foo_HEADERS` and the list of files in `foo/*.h` consistent:

1. Use a `Makefile.am` include file to list all the files. Let's call it `foo-headers.mk`.
2. Have `Makefile.am` define the variable and include the include file:

   ```
   foodir = $(includedir)/foo
   foo_HEADERS =
   include foo-headers.mk
   ```
3. Now `foo-headers.mk` will consist of exactly one line per header file which all look like

   ```
   foo_HEADERS += foo/moo.h
   ```

   This is a very long list to maintain manually, but we can have the computer help us maintain the `foo-headers.mk` file by checking and pointing out any inconsistencies.

   `foo-headers.mk` will be version controlled alongside `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`.
4. To prevent any inconsistencies between the file list `$(srcdir)/foo/*.h` and the content of `foo-headers.mk` going unnoticed, we add a rule to `Makefile.am` which checks for that consistency, prints a useful error message and aborts any build if the two are inconsistent.

   ```
   all-local:
       @set -e; \
       LC_ALL="C"; \
       cd "$(srcdir)"; \
       oldmk="$(abs_srcdir)/foo-headers.mk"; \
       newmk="$(abs_builddir)/foo-headers.mk.$$$$"; \
       for hfile in foo/*.h; do \
         printf 'foo_HEADERS += %s\n' "$$hfile"; \
       done | sort > "$(abs_builddir)/header-list.mk.new$$$$"; \
       if cmp "$$oldmk" "$$newmk" > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
         echo "foo-headers.mk is up to date, nothing to do."; \
         rm -f "$$newmk"; \
       else \
         printf "Error: foo-headers.mk and the list of foo/*.h are inconsistent.\n       Update $$oldmk\n       from   $$newmk?\n"; \
         exit 1; \
       fi
   ```

   This code will run every time you run "make" or "make all" or "make distcheck", so you will never build a release tarball which contains a `foo/*.h` file list inconsistent with the content of `foo-headers.mk`.

Now you still need to maintain the list of `foo/*.h` files inside `foo-headers.mk` every time the list of `foo/*.h` files changes, but every time the two diverge, your build will fail, and you have a file which would be the `foo-headers.mk` for the current list of `foo/*.h` files ready for use (`cp`, `diff -u`, whatever) in case that helps.

I have put a complete minimum working example at https://github.com/ndim/so76847289.

You can improve on the Makefile rule by using less portable commands which produce nicer output like `diff -u` instead of `cmp` after checking that `diff` and `diff -u` exist and work as expected in `configure.ac`, but that is not strictly necessary to demonstrate the principle of doing automatic consistency checks, and so I have left that out.

You could also choose to just update the `foo-headers.mk` file if it is found to not reflect the `foo/*.h` file list, by replacing `exit 1` with `mv -f "$$newmk" "$$oldmk"`. This means that building can update the `$srcdir`, though, and will require a subsequent commit to version control. You might or might not want a simple build to be able to trigger that.